# Number of API calls used while extracting data from Marketo

Tags: api, rest, marketo

Is there anyway to find out how many webapi calls that are used against quota when doing rest API call (or soap api call) reading leads from a list? Please note that this is purely read-only, where we are getting data from a static list of leads, which are added using a smart campaign.

We are bringing in 40 attributes from the Marketo lead record total 1600 chars. Depending on need, we might need to stage anywhere from 200K to 1 million records into a static list. We are successfully extracting all that data, but we would like to find out how many API calls are being utilized.

Answer (score 1):

Each authenticated request to an endpoint counts as a call.  You can also the usage API to see your daily usage: http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-daily-usage/